# Monotouch release build crash when i try to get some data from the server.

Tags: xamarin.ios

On debug(development mode on device) it works very fine but when i make the  ipa on release it crashes exactly when i try to get the data from the server. I specify that the app works on release mode but exactly when i try to get the data it crashes.

```
Date/Time:       2012-07-03 15:02:07.045 +0300
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104`enter code here`

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4c32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ddf208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd8298 abort + 88
3   PrintStand                      0x01277ec6 0x1000 + 19361478
4   PrintStand                      0x012909a2 0x1000 + 19462562
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33de97e6 _sigtramp + 42
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ddf208 pthread_kill + 48
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd8298 abort + 88
8   PrintStand                      0x01318eda 0x1000 + 20020954
9   PrintStand                      0x01318f16 0x1000 + 20021014
10  PrintStand                      0x0126dc3a 0x1000 + 19319866
11  PrintStand                      0x0126df04 0x1000 + 19320580
12  PrintStand                      0x012e176a 0x1000 + 19793770
13  PrintStand                      0x012e24f4 0x1000 + 19797236
14  PrintStand                      0x012e25b6 0x1000 + 19797430
15  PrintStand                      0x01279da6 0x1000 + 19369382
16  PrintStand                      0x01279f52 0x1000 + 19369810
17  PrintStand                      0x01278c24 0x1000 + 19364900
18  PrintStand                      0x011fd320 0x1000 + 18858784
19  PrintStand                      0x00d282d4 0x1000 + 13791956
20  PrintStand                      0x00d4da9c 0x1000 + 13945500
21  PrintStand                      0x00d31844 0x1000 + 13830212
22  PrintStand                      0x00d2816c 0x1000 + 13791596
23  PrintStand                      0x00d26fd4 0x1000 + 13787092
24  PrintStand                      0x00d25cac 0x1000 + 13782188
25  PrintStand                      0x00d25aac 0x1000 + 13781676
26  PrintStand                      0x00d2768c 0x1000 + 13788812
27  PrintStand                      0x00d2a370 0x1000 + 13800304
28  PrintStand                      0x00d28804 0x1000 + 13793284
29  PrintStand                      0x00d267c4 0x1000 + 13785028
30  PrintStand                      0x00d25c7c 0x1000 + 13782140
31  PrintStand                      0x00d25b68 0x1000 + 13781864
32  PrintStand                      0x00d284e8 0x1000 + 13792488
33  PrintStand                      0x00d4da9c 0x1000 + 13945500
34  PrintStand                      0x00d31844 0x1000 + 13830212
35  PrintStand                      0x00d2816c 0x1000 + 13791596
36  PrintStand                      0x00d26fd4 0x1000 + 13787092
37  PrintStand                      0x00d25cac 0x1000 + 13782188
38  PrintStand                      0x00d25aac 0x1000 + 13781676
39  PrintStand                      0x00d2768c 0x1000 + 13788812
40  PrintStand                      0x00d2a370 0x1000 + 13800304
41  PrintStand                      0x00d28804 0x1000 + 13793284
42  PrintStand                      0x00d267c4 0x1000 + 13785028
43  PrintStand                      0x00d25c7c 0x1000 + 13782140
44  PrintStand                      0x00d25b68 0x1000 + 13781864
45  PrintStand                      0x00d25654 0x1000 + 13780564
46  PrintStand                      0x00cfc25c 0x1000 + 13611612
47  PrintStand                      0x00cfc1d8 0x1000 + 13611480
48  PrintStand                      0x00cf9960 0x1000 + 13601120
49  PrintStand                      0x00cf981c 0x1000 + 13600796
50  PrintStand                      0x00cf9748 0x1000 + 13600584
51  PrintStand                      0x0103caec 0x1000 + 17021676
52  PrintStand                      0x0103e4ac 0x1000 + 17028268
53  PrintStand                      0x00bcd81c 0x1000 + 12371996
54  PrintStand                      0x011b7578 0x1000 + 18572664
55  PrintStand                      0x01265cd4 0x1000 + 19287252
56  PrintStand                      0x012e0f58 0x1000 + 19791704
57  PrintStand                      0x0132e170 0x1000 + 20107632
58  UIKit                           0x31861ef4 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 540
59  UIKit                           0x31860fd2 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1070
60  UIKit                           0x3186075c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 200
61  UIKit                           0x31804f30 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 176
62  CoreFoundation                  0x315331f4 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
63  QuartzCore                      0x35449a9e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
64  QuartzCore                      0x354496b6 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 210
65  QuartzCore                      0x3544d83c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 220
66  QuartzCore                      0x3544d578 CA::Transaction::commit() + 308
67  QuartzCore                      0x354454b2 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 50
68  CoreFoundation                  0x315a8b14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
69  CoreFoundation                  0x315a6d50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
70  CoreFoundation                  0x315a70aa __CFRunLoopRun + 754
71  CoreFoundation                  0x3152a49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
72  CoreFoundation                  0x3152a366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
73  GraphicsServices                0x32a03432 GSEventRunModal + 130
74  UIKit                           0x3182fcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
75  PrintStand                      0x01002220 0x1000 + 16781856
76  PrintStand                      0x00bc37d8 0x1000 + 12330968
77  PrintStand                      0x011b7578 0x1000 + 18572664
78  PrintStand                      0x01265cd4 0x1000 + 19287252
79  PrintStand                      0x012e0f58 0x1000 + 19791704
80  PrintStand                      0x012e3c38 0x1000 + 19803192
81  PrintStand                      0x012e7588 0x1000 + 19817864
82  PrintStand                      0x0126a728 0x1000 + 19306280
83  PrintStand                      0x012628d6 0x1000 + 19273942
84  PrintStand                      0x00bb3854 0x1000 + 12265556
```

Comment: You should get a symbolicated crash report and/or the device log, without more information it not possible to know what's going on.

Comment: Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:   r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ed7ed98      r6: 0x01413612      r7: 0x2fdfb75c
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x01413630     r11: 0x02c33d48
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfb750      lr: 0x33ddf20f      pc: 0x37f4c32c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Comment: can you help about this error?

Comment: Can you get the iOS device log too? (open it in MonoDevelop's menu: View -> Pads -> iOS Device Log, Connect, then make your app crash again).

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with the device log in monotouch.The xcode did not gave the details on the error it gave.

Comment: Then you should add an answer yourself so other people can figure out what the issue was.

Comment: The issue was from a released control that i added to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
Incident Identifier: 3480F59E-A1C3-43EE-AACA-B6BA7804CCF8
CrashReporter Key:   a62caa0c7da6b2d1ddedda18b8354a223eb8d0b9
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         PrintStand [8017]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C51C71E3-8F48-4954-9D08-D79AE147069B/MediawirePrintStandMobilePresentation.app/PrintStand
Identifier:      PrintStand
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-03 16:07:15.743 +0300
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4c32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ddf208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd8298 abort + 88
3   PrintStand                      0x01276ec6 0x1000 + 19357382
4   PrintStand                      0x0128f9a2 0x1000 + 19458466
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33de97e6 _sigtramp + 42
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ddf208 pthread_kill + 48
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd8298 abort + 88
8   PrintStand                      0x01317eda 0x1000 + 20016858
9   PrintStand                      0x01317efc 0x1000 + 20016892
10  PrintStand                      0x012627ea 0x1000 + 19273706
11  PrintStand                      0x01276a54 0x1000 + 19356244
12  PrintStand                      0x01276b22 0x1000 + 19356450
13  PrintStand                      0x0128e6c6 0x1000 + 19453638
14  ???                             0x02a71000 0 + 44503040
15  PrintStand                      0x00ca9be0 0x1000 + 13274080
16  PrintStand                      0x0110b798 0x1000 + 17868696
17  PrintStand                      0x01264cd4 0x1000 + 19283156
18  PrintStand                      0x012dff58 0x1000 + 19787608
19  PrintStand                      0x0132d170 0x1000 + 20103536
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3152e3f6 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
21  UIKit                           0x3181ce00 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
22  UIKit                           0x3181cdbc -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
23  UIKit                           0x3181cd9a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
24  UIKit                           0x3181cb0a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 486
25  UIKit                           0x3181d442 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 470
26  UIKit                           0x3180fb80 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5216
27  CoreFoundation                  0x315a8b14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
28  CoreFoundation                  0x315a6d50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
29  CoreFoundation                  0x315a70aa __CFRunLoopRun + 754
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3152a49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
31  CoreFoundation                  0x3152a366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
32  GraphicsServices                0x32a03432 GSEventRunModal + 130
33  UIKit                           0x3182fcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
34  PrintStand                      0x00cd473c 0x1000 + 13449020
35  PrintStand                      0x00bc2c08 0x1000 + 12327944
36  PrintStand                      0x0110b798 0x1000 + 17868696
37  PrintStand                      0x01264cd4 0x1000 + 19283156
38  PrintStand                      0x012dff58 0x1000 + 19787608
39  PrintStand                      0x012e2c38 0x1000 + 19799096
40  PrintStand                      0x012e6588 0x1000 + 19813768
41  PrintStand                      0x01269728 0x1000 + 19302184
42  PrintStand                      0x012618d6 0x1000 + 19269846
43  PrintStand                      0x00bb2c84 0x1000 + 12262532

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3477af04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3477ac22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4ccd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9af36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9acc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x315a83ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x315a7124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3152a49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3152a366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x31d4ac9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4c628 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da4b1a nanosleep + 138
2   PrintStand                      0x0130cf60 0x1000 + 19971936
3   PrintStand                      0x012f38ba 0x1000 + 19867834
4   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
5   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
6   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c06c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   PrintStand                      0x01312ff6 0x1000 + 19996662
2   PrintStand                      0x012f5724 0x1000 + 19875620
3   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
4   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
5   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c3a8 kevent + 24
1   PrintStand                      0x012f438a 0x1000 + 19870602
2   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
3   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
4   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c06c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   PrintStand                      0x01312ff6 0x1000 + 19996662
2   PrintStand                      0x012f5724 0x1000 + 19875620
3   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
4   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
5   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4ccd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9af36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9acc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c054 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   PrintStand                      0x01313054 0x1000 + 19996756
2   PrintStand                      0x012ada72 0x1000 + 19581554
3   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
4   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
5   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ed7ed98      r6: 0x01412612      r7: 0x2fdfd334
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x01412630     r11: 0x02af74a4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfd328      lr: 0x33ddf20f      pc: 0x37f4c32c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

    enter code here
```